# What is the correct way to draw the end groups of polylactic acid?

Tags: polymers, structural-formula

I came across two different ways to draw the end groups of [polylactic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylactic_acid):

[image: Polylactic acid] ([source](http://www.jnanobiotechnology.com/content/figures/1477-3155-9-55-4-l.jpg))

AND:

[image: Polylactic acid] ([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PLA_from_lactic_acid_%26_lactide.png))

Which one is the correct way?

Comment: Why do you think it would make a real difference in **poly**lactic acid?

Comment: @Mithoron I guess it wouldn't; but then why do people bother drawing redundant information?

Comment: Well, maybe simpler form would be confusing for newbies...

Comment: As @Mithoron said, both are correct but the first is more compact.

Comment: The graphical representation standards given in the [IUPAC Compendium of Polymer Terminology and Nomenclature _(Purple Book)_](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-PB2-Online-June2014.pdf) are not really clear about end-groups. However, note that the subscript _n_ should be printed in italic type.

Comment: @bon this reduces the degree of polymerization by 2...